# Automatically switch language based on visitor's country

Tags: redirect, multi-language, domain, hosting, ip

I want to switch domains based on the visitor's country since I have one for US/CAN/International in English and Chinese for China.

I want to know if it's possible to redirect my English site to my Chinese site when someone from china types my En domain.

cheers

Comment: This is possible, but it's not always the best user experience. Users may be on an IP address from one country but be more fluent in another language. So usually it's best to have a primary domain and link off to all the various languages from there. If you do decide you want to do this, you will likely want to set up a child theme that handles IP detection and redirection.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I figured it out :)